# Can't send a Month as a parameter

Tags: java, date, netbeans, jfreechart

I'm using `jFreeChart` to make a Gantt Chart and for adding each task im using `Enumeration` utility for gets elements from an `Hashtable`. I can send the year and the day, but get an Exception when a try to send Month like a parameter with this line:

```
hT.get(obj).getFechaFin().getMonth()
```

Wherein `hT` is an `Hashtable` and `obj` is an index. I understand that `getMonth()` returns an `int`. It throws:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" 
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requires start <= end.
```

Then changed that code line for `Calendar.MARCH` it worked and generated the chart. And it also returns a `int`, their indexes begins both with 0 being January the first month. So why isn't working? I'm using `jCalendar-1.4.jar` to easily get dates from a component.

```
//here I load the Hashtable and I generate the Chart

public static IntervalCategoryDataset createDataset(){
    final TaskSeries s1 = new TaskSeries("Scheduled");

    for (Enumeration e = hT.keys(); e.hasMoreElements();) {
        Object obj = e.nextElement();
        s1.add(new Task(hT.get(obj).getTarea().toString(),
            new SimpleTimePeriod(
                date(hT.get(obj).getFechaInicio().getDay(),
                     hT.get(obj).getFechaInicio().getMonth(),                                              
                     hT.get(obj).getFechaInicio().getYear()),
                date(hT.get(obj).getFechaFin().getDay(),
                     hT.get(obj).getFechaFin().getMonth(),                                              
                     hT.get(obj).getFechaFin().getYear()))));
    }

    final TaskSeriesCollection collection = new TaskSeriesCollection();
    collection.add(s1);
    return collection;
}

//and here receives the month parameter 
private static Date date(final int day, final int month, final int year){
     final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
     calendar.set(year,month,day);
     final Date result = calendar.getTime();
     return result;
}
```

I need to use `hT.get(obj).getFechaFin().getMonth()` 'cause it is saved in a binary file. Is there a way to convert to `Calender.MONTH` format?

Comment: That is the expected behavior when `start > end`. If it looks OK in the debugger, you might examine your larger code for a race condition.

Comment: What type do `getFechaInicio` and `getFechaFin` return? And what values?

Comment: @herMa694 Post further details as edits to the Question rather than as Comment.

Answer (score 1):

I found a simple way to do it:

```
   public static IntervalCategoryDataset createDataset(){
    final TaskSeries s1 = new TaskSeries("Tareas");


    for (Enumeration e = hT.keys(); e.hasMoreElements();) {
        Object obj = e.nextElement();
        s1.add(new Task(hT.get(obj).getTarea().toString(),
                new SimpleTimePeriod(hT.get(obj).getFechaInicio(), hT.get(obj).getFechaFin())));

    }      
    final TaskSeriesCollection collection = new TaskSeriesCollection();
    collection.add(s1);
    return collection;
}
```

`private static Date date` is not really necessary. Cause I'm already passing a Date value in `hT.get(obj).getFechaInicio()`. That method only construct a Date value by passing the `int` values of the day, month and year. Now I can generate Gantt chart with this.

Comment: This is the better approach; your answer will be more useful to others if you add some detail about data types, as @Ole V.V. suggests [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55646685/cant-send-a-month-as-a-parameter#comment97985776_55646685).